# What happens to new events when one is retrying in the same partition in Event Hub Azure?

Tags: partitioning, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to understand how the partitions are executing the events when there is retry policy in place for the event hub and I can't find an answer to what happens to new events when one got an error and is retrying in the same partition in the event hub?

I'm guessing that the one that got an error shouldn't block new ones from executing and when it reties it should be put at the end of the partition, so any other events that got in the partition after that event got an error should be executed in order without any blockage.

Can someone explain what is actually happening in a scenario like that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer precisely without some understanding of the application context.  The below assumes the current generation of the Azure SDK for .NET, though conceptually the answer will be similar for others.

Retries during publishing are performed within the client, which treats each publishing operation an independent and isolated.  When your application calls `SendAsync`, the client will attempt to publish them and will apply its retry policy in the scope of that call.  When the `SendAsync` call completes, you'll have a deterministic answer of whether the call succeeded or failed.

If the `SendAsync` call throws, the retry policy has already been applied and either the exception was fatal or all retries were exhausted.  The operation is complete and the client is no longer trying to publish those events.

If your application makes a single `SendAsync` call then, in the majority of cases, it will understand the outcome of the publishing operation and the order of events is preserved.  If your application is calling `SendAsync` concurrently, then it is possible that events will arrive out of order - either due to network latency or retries.

While the majority of the time, the outcome of a call is fully deterministic, some corner cases do exist.  For example, if the `SendAsync` call encounters a timeout, it is ambiguous whether or not the service received the events.   The client will retry, which may produce duplicates.  If your application sees a `TimeoutException` surface, then it cannot be sure whether or not the events were successfully published.